# Terraform is not deleting CloudWatch rules

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I have Lambdas that are linked to CloudWatch rules. When I run `terraform destroy` to delete them (both the lambdas and their associated rules, it successfully deletes the lambdas, and then when I try to delete the rules, I get

```
    Error deleting CloudWatch Event Rule: ValidationException: Rule can't be deleted since it has targets.
        status code: 400
```

I even put a long sleep between the deletion of the lambdas and the rules but I still get the same error. Does terraform not detach the lambdas from their targets before it deletes them? Is there a separate command to do this from terraform?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] that we can run to see the behaviour?

Answer (score 7):

It really seems to be a [Terraform issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1479).

No decent workarounds were provided yet. Unfortunately, you'll probably have to manually edit the even rule and delete its targets.

If you fixed this some other way, please share.

Comment: This issue occurs in the new version as well. the provider.aws v3.28.0 has this issue. opened a issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18519

Comment: Even the same with provider.aws v4.12.0

Comment: still there provider.aws 4.49.0

Comment: also ran into this with 5.31

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. Deleted all targets from the rule manually using CLI and then terraform succeeded to delete the rule. To remove the targets from the rule please follow the instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75588465/5718591)