# An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteRule operation: Rule can't be deleted since it has targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I got this issue when deleting event on aws cloudwatch

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteRule
>   operation: Rule can't be deleted since it has targets.

My command line is :

```
aws events delete-rule --name event-schedule --force
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the solution, we should remove target first:

> aws events remove-targets --rule event-schedule
>   --ids dev-transaction

then delete-rule:

```
aws events delete-rule --name event-schedule
```

Answer (score 3):

The strange thing is, if you put wrong ids of the target AWS CLI won't reject it. And if you face hard time to find the actual ID of the targets run the below command first to see the list of targets and IDs of those -

```bash
    aws events list-targets-by-rule --rule "YourRuleName"
```

It will respond with the list of targets like -

```json
    {
        "Targets": [
            {
                "Id": "id-of-target",
                "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:region:acc:function:name"
            },
            {
                "Id": "id-of-another-target",
                "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:region:acc:function:name"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now, to remove any(or all) target from the rule run -

```bash
    aws events remove-targets --rule "YourRuleName" --ids "id-of-target"
```

Hope this helps.